# CSS and radio buttons

Tags: html, css

I'm close but I can't get my radio buttons to line up next to a label.
I've change the css a million times but I can't seem to get all my text boxes, radio buttons and commment box to line up under each other.  Specifically, the second radio button isn't lining up with the rest of the stuff.

Any ideas?
Appreciate it!

Here's the code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/NpJ55/

My html and css:

```
<fieldset>
    <label for="name" class="formlabel">Name:</label>
    <input id="fName" name="name" type="text" class="forminput" />

    <label for="co" class="formlabel">Company:</label>
    <input id="fCo" name="co" type="text" class="forminput" />

    <label for="email" class="formlabel">Email:</label>
    <input id="fEmail" name="email" type="text" class="forminput" />

    <label for="phone" class="formlabel">Phone:</label>
    <input id="fPhone" name="phone" type="text" class="forminput" />

    <label for="contact" class="formlabel">Contact:</label>
    <div id="radio_form">
        <input id="radio_form_1" name="Sales" type="radio" value="Sales" />
        <label for="radio_form_1">Sales</label>
        <input id="radio_form_2" name="Technical" type="radio" value="Technical" />
        <label for="radio_form_2">Technical</label>
    </div>

    <label for="name" class="formlabel">Comments:</label>
    <textarea name="comments" rows="5" cols="50" class="forminput"></textarea>
    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="submit" class="forminput" value="Submit" />
</fieldset>

.formlabel {
    clear:left;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 1em 0;
    padding:0 0.5em 0 0;
    text-align:right;
    width:8em;
}

.forminput {
    float:left;
    margin:0 0.5em 0.5em 0;
}

fieldset {
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    border-radius:8px;
}

input, textarea {
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:solid 1px #999;
    padding:2px;
}

#submit {
    background:grey;
    height:30px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px;
    color:white;
    font:family:Arial;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:15px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#submit:hover {
    background:#4498e1;
}

#radio_form input {
    float: left;
}
#radio_form label {
    float: left;
}
#radio_form label + input {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the radio input elements to be *all* on the same line, or do you want them each on their own line (along with their relevant `label`)?

Comment: As a side note the `for` attribute in your labels needs to match the `id` for it's corresponding input field. In addition to that your two radio buttons should have the same `name` in order to even work as radio buttons. As you have it right now they act more like check boxes since you can select both or none of them.

Comment: David Thomas: I meant to have the radio buttons underneath each other but failed to be specific.  My mistake.

Comment: rosscowar: thanks for taking the time to explain the proper way to do things, still learning the basics...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well - without making too many changes... http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/NpJ55/3/

```
#radio_form{
    float: left;
}
```

And drop the `#radio_form ...` rules!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the rule:

```
#radio_form label + input {
    clear: both;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NpJ55/1/)**

Comment: I'm not sure; I *think* (and I realise it's ambiguous as written) that he wants each radio `input` on different lines (along with its label), but lined up so that each radio appears in the same vertical 'line' with the text-inputs.

Comment: @DavidThomas - yeah I wasn't clear on this one either. But I like the output mine gives ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/gJKb6/)

```
#radio_form {
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 13px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 3px 7px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid having to fight with floats by using `inline-block` instead

http://jsfiddle.net/NpJ55/8/

[image]

```
.fieldwrap {
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.formlabel {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:right;
    width:8em;    
    font-size: 24px;
}

.radiolabel {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.radio {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.forminput {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Will take a look at inline-block, don't know that technique, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Or conversely, add the rule:

```
#radio_form {
    float: left;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NpJ55/2/)

Comment: sorry, typo, meant `#radio_form {` not `radio_form input`. Had it right in the fiddle, but copied the wrong line. Answer updated. Thanks, @putvande